# Tesseract adds "xlz" when given specific Chinese character

Tags: tesseract

When running tesseract with a specific Chinese character, 對, the text output has "xlz" prepended before the recognized output.

Ie, running

`tesseract sub0089w.png debugOut -l ARYuanB5-MD --dpi 72 --psm 6 -c preserve_interword_spaces=1`

Outputs

```
xlz
對
```

Here's the input image:

[image]

Why?  How can I fix it?

I've retrained the model using the exact font used in the image (with training data).  While it works very well on a few hundred lines of text only this specific character outputs the extra "xlz" text.

```
$ tesseract -v
tesseract 5.3.2-29-g3ac6
 leptonica-1.76.0
  libgif 5.1.4 : libjpeg 6b (libjpeg-turbo 1.5.3) : libpng 1.6.34 : libtiff 4.0.9 : zlib 1.2.11 : libwebp 1.0.0
 Found AVX
 Found SSE4.1
 Found OpenMP 201511
 Found libarchive 3.3.2 zlib/1.2.11 liblzma/5.2.4 bz2lib/1.0.6 liblz4/1.8.1
 Found libcurl/7.61.1 OpenSSL/1.1.1c zlib/1.2.11 brotli/1.0.6 libidn2/2.2.0 libpsl/0.20.2 (+libidn2/2.0.5) libssh/0.9.0/openssl/zlib nghttp2/1.33.0
```